# Least upper bound not an element in the cut

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In his proof "Any bounded nonempty subset $\mathbb{R}$ has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$", Enderton showed that the least upper bound is just $\bigcup A$. Since by definition $x\subseteq \bigcup A\quad \& \quad x\in A$ .
In the case $x=\bigcup A\quad \& \quad x\in A$, $x$ becomes the largest element in $A$, but this cannot be true since the Dedekind Cut is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ that must have no largest element.
How do you explain that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing between sets and sets of sets.

$A$ is a set of sets of rational numbers. While Dedekind cuts have no upper bound, there might very well be an upper bound to a *set of* Dedekind cuts.

Note that $x,y\in A$ the $x\subseteq y$ or $y\subseteq x$. Then $\bigcup A=\{z\in\mathbb Q\mid \exists x\in A(z\in x)\}$. That for itself is a Dedekind cut.

In particular, $\bar A=A\cup\{\bigcup A\}$ is a set of Dedekind cuts, and it is simple to see that every $x\in A$ is a subset of $\bigcup A$, as well $\bigcup A$ is a subset of itself. Therefore ordered by inclusion, $\bar A$ has a maximal element.

Comment: @user11750: Thanks :-)